# how to fetch array keys with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, arrays, key

Good afternoon. I have an array with some keys, and values in them. I then need to fetch the array keys and not the data in them. I want to do this with jQuery. I know for example that PHP has a function called array_keys(); which takes the array as a parameter and gives you an array back with each key in each index.

This is what I came up with, and it works... the only problem is that it seems so unefficent;

```
var foo = [];
foo['alfa'] = "first item";
foo['beta'] = "second item";

for (var key in foo) {
    console.log(key);
}
```

This will output;

```
alfa
beta
```

But is there any predefined function for this, as in PHP or any other more effective way of getting this?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

you can use the `each` function:

```
var a = {};
a['alfa'] = 0;
a['beta'] = 1;
$.each(a, function(key, value) {
      alert(key)
});
```

it has several nice shortcuts/tricks: [check the gory details here](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.each)

Comment: and what does $.each() use internally for objects?! This method will be slower because the use of a callback function will increase the length of the scope chain and therefore take longer to resolve the reference to a's properties

Comment: Don't forget to use curved brackets instead of squared brackets to define the array!

Comment: console.log(key) would work better for a long list etc

Answer (score 51):

Using jQuery, easiest way to get array of keys from object is following:

```
$.map(obj, function(element,index) {return index})
```

In your case, it will return this array: `["alfa", "beta"]`

Comment: One minor difference from Object.keys is that JQuery version (tested with JQuery v1.6.2 and v1.8.2) returns array keys (indices) as integers as opposed to Object.keys returning those as strings. Though this wont be an issue in 99.999% of the cases...

Answer (score 36):

In modern browsers, the easiest way to get the keys of an array is `Object.keys()`.  For example:

```
console.log( Object.keys( {'a':1,'b':2} ) );
```

Comment: This is only in javascript 1.8.5+

For browser support see the table at bottom of page here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Answer (score 8):

#### Don't Reinvent the Wheel, Use [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/)

*I know the OP specifically mentioned **jQuery** but I wanted to put an answer here to introduce people to the helpful **Underscore** library if they are not aware of it already.*

By leveraging the `keys` method in the [Underscore library](http://underscorejs.org/#keys), you can simply do the following:

```
_.keys(foo)  #=> ["alfa", "beta"]
```

Plus, there's a plethora of other useful functions that are worth perusing.

Answer (score 5):

Use an object (key/value pairs, the nearest JavaScript has to an associative array) for this and not the array object. Other than that, I believe that is the most elegant way

```
var foo = {};
foo['alfa'] = "first item";
foo['beta'] = "second item";

for (var key in foo) {
        console.log(key);
}
```

*Note: JavaScript doesn't guarantee any particular order for the properties. So you cannot expect the property that was defined first to appear first, it might come last.*

**EDIT:**

In response to your comment, I believe that this article best sums up the cases for why arrays in JavaScript should not be used in this fashion -

- **["Associative Arrays" considered Harmful](http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/)**

Comment: Thanks for the note, luckily it won't matter for me in this particular case. :) But just one question, why is it better to have it as an object (associative array)?

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this function I created...

```
Object.getKeys = function(obj, add) {
    if(obj === undefined || obj === null) {
        return undefined;
    }
    var keys = [];
    if(add !== undefined) {
        keys = jQuery.merge(keys, add);
    }
    for(key in obj) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                keys.push(key);
        }
    }
    return keys;
};
```

I think you could set obj to self or something better in the first test.
It seems sometimes I'm checking if it's empty too so I did it that way.
Also I don't think {} is Object.* or at least there's a problem finding the function getKeys on the Object that way.
Maybe you're suppose to put prototype first, but that seems to cause a conflict with GreenSock etc.

Comment: Even here it's done something like that. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys I thought one was suppose to just use keys() but it was not fully implimented yet so I rolled my own as I often do.