# php function array_keys equivalent in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, logic, business-logic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to fetch array keys with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254227/how-to-fetch-array-keys-with-jquery)

php built-in function `array_keys(),` equivalent in jquery
is there any built in function in jquery similar to that of php `array_keys(),`.

please suggest

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254227/how-to-fetch-array-keys-with-jquery

Comment: Btw: Arrays in Javascript can only have numerical keys, there's no such thing as an associative array. It only can be simulated by an object ([but has flaws](http://blog.kevinchisholm.com/javascript/associative-arrays-in-javascript/))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to define your own function to get the same functionality. Try this:

```
function arrayKeys(input) {
    var output = new Array();
    var counter = 0;
    for (i in input) {
        output[counter++] = i;
    } 
    return output; 
}

arrayKeys({"one":1, "two":2, "three":3}); // returns ["one","two","three"]
```

Answer (score 3):

No there isn't anything specific in jQuery for this. There is a javascript method but it is not widely supported yet [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) so people don't use it for generic projects. Best thing i could think of is

```
var keys = $.map(your_object, function(value, key) {
  return key;
});
```

Comment: This is the best answer, but `Object.keys()` is widely supported now, including IE9+ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Answer (score 3):

You don't need jQuery or any other library for this -- it's a standard part of Javascript.

```
for(var key in myObject) {
    alert(key);
}
```

That should be sufficient for you to loop through the object. But if you want to actually get the keys into their own array (ie turn it into a genuine clone of the php function), then it's fairly trivial to extend the above:

```
function array_keys(myObject) {
    output = [];
    for(var key in myObject) {
        output.push(key);
    }
    return output;
}
```

Note, there are caveats with using the `for(..in..)` technique for objects that have properties or methods that you don't want to include (eg core system properties), but for a simple object that you've created yourself or from a JSON string, it's ideal.

(For more info on the caveats, see http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/09/26/for-in-intrigue/)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [PHPJS](http://phpjs.org), a project that aims to reproduce many PHP functions in vanilla JavaScript with minimal dependencies. In your case, you want [`array_keys`](http://phpjs.org/functions/array_keys/).

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript there's no such thing like associative arrays. Objects (object literals) handle similar cases.

```
var keys = [], i = 0;    
for( keys[ i++ ] in yourObject );
```

And now `keys` contains all `yourObject` property names (keys).