# unwanted returning empty object

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, object, dynamic

In the following code I am attempting (with Jquery) to create objects with arrays and then call those objects to appear in an existing DIV when I click a link.

I have basically created a matrix that is 5x5; in which, each "box" contains a link.

The current code that I have written returns this: [object object]. (which I believe is an empty array.

HTML (I am only showing one row of the matrix, there are four more):

```
<body>

<div id="container">

<div id="logo" class="center">

<img src="jeoparody.png" />

</div>

<div id="wood" class="center">

    <ul id="categories">
        <li>The Global Age</li>
        <li>Age of Revolutions</li>
        <li>Era of Global Wars</li>
        <li>The Post War Period</li>
        <li>Geography</li>
   </ul>

<div class="clear"></div>

<hr />

<div class="clear"></div>

    <ul id="rowOne" class="center">
        <li><a href="#">$100</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">$100</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">$100</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">$100</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">$100</a></li>
    </ul>

<div class="clear"></div>

    <ul id="rowTwo" class="center">
        <li><a href="#">$200</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">$200</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">$200</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">$200</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">$200</a></li>
    </ul>

<div class="clear"></div>

    <ul id="rowThree" class="center">
        <li><a href="#">$300</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">$300</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">$300</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">$300</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">$300</a></li>
    </ul>

<div class="clear"></div>

<ul id="rowFour" class="center">
    <li><a href="#">$400</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">$400</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">$400</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">$400</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">$400</a></li>
 </ul>

<div class="clear"></div>

<ul id="rowFive" class="center">
    <li><a href="#">$500</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">$500</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">$500</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">$500</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">$500</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="footer" class="center"></div>

</div>

<div id="clueContainer" class="center"></div>

</body>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

/***The objects that I am creating with arrays***/   
var columnOne = {
    '$100':'On the world political map, where were some of the major states and empires located about 1500 A.D. (C.E.)?',
    '$200':'What were the artistic, literary, and intellectual ideas of the Renaissance?',
    '$300':'Where were the five world religions located around 1500 A.D. (C.E.)?',
    '$400':'What were the regional trading patterns about 1500 A.D. (C.E.)?',
    '$500':'Why were the regional trading patterns important?'
};

var columnTwo = {
    '$100':'A',
    '$200':'B',
    '$300':'C',
    '$400':'D',
    '$500':'E'
};

var columnThree = {
    '$100':'F',
    '$200':'G',
    '$300':'H',
    '$400':'I',
    '$500':'J'
};

var columnFour = {
    '$100':'K',
    '$200':'L',
    '$300':'M',
    '$400':'N',
    '$500':'O'
};

var columnFive = {
    '$100':'P',
    '$200':'Q',
    '$300':'R',
    '$400':'S',
    '$500':'T'
};

/***To call back each object when the link is clicked***/   
$('li').on('click', 'a', function() {
    var foo = $(this).text();
    $("#clueContainer").text(columnOne, columnTwo, columnThree, columnFour, columnFive[foo]);
});

/***makes the main screen disappear and the new DIV appear***/
$("#container").click(function(){
$("#container").hide(function(){
    $("#clueContainer").show(function(){
    });
});

/***makes the new DIV disappear and the main screen reappear***/
$("#clueContainer").click(function(){
$("#clueContainer").hide(function(){
    $("#container").show(function(){
    });
});
});
});
});
```

Does anyone have any idea for a solution?

Comment: *"The current code that I have written returns this: [object object]. (which I believe is an empty array"* `[object Object]` is what you get when you call `toString` (explicitly or implicitly) on an object that doesn't override it with something more useful. The object is not necessarily empty. Note that your `columnOne` and such are objects, not arrays. (`Array#toString` does a `join` by default.)

Comment: check out my last edit! there's a link try to use that to get only your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update based on further clarifications from comments below

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    /***The objects that I am creating with arrays***/   
    var columnOne = {
        '$100':'On the world political map, where were some of the major states and empires located about 1500 A.D. (C.E.)?',
        '$200':'What were the artistic, literary, and intellectual ideas of the Renaissance?',
        '$300':'Where were the five world religions located around 1500 A.D. (C.E.)?',
        '$400':'What were the regional trading patterns about 1500 A.D. (C.E.)?',
        '$500':'Why were the regional trading patterns important?'
    };

    var columnTwo = {
        '$100':'A',
        '$200':'B',
        '$300':'C',
        '$400':'D',
        '$500':'E'
    };

    var columnThree = {
        '$100':'F',
        '$200':'G',
        '$300':'H',
        '$400':'I',
        '$500':'J'
    };

    var columnFour = {
        '$100':'K',
        '$200':'L',
        '$300':'M',
        '$400':'N',
        '$500':'O'
    };
    $('#rowFour').data('qstns', columnFour);

    var columnFive = {
        '$100':'P',
        '$200':'Q',
        '$300':'R',
        '$400':'S',
        '$500':'T'
    };
    $('#rowFive').data('qstns', columnFive);

    /***To call back each object when the link is clicked***/   
    var $rows = $('#rowOne, #rowTwo, #rowThree, #rowFour, #rowFive');
    var columns = [columnOne, columnTwo, columnThree, columnFour, columnFive];
    $('li').on('click', 'a', function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        var foo = $this.text();
        var qstns = columns[$this.closest('li').index()];
        $("#clueContainer").text(qstns[foo]);
    });

    /***makes the main screen disappear and the new DIV appear***/
    $("#container").click(function(){
        $("#container").hide(function(){
            $("#clueContainer").show(function(){
            });
        });
    });

    /***makes the new DIV disappear and the main screen reappear***/
    $("#clueContainer").click(function(){
        $("#clueContainer").hide(function(){
            $("#container").show(function(){
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rStuM/)

Comment: This works; however, I would like only the question to appear in the DIV. ex.:'$500':'Why were the regional trading patterns important?' would like 'Why were the regional trading patterns important?' to appear only.

Comment: @justLearning what do you mean by *only the question to appear in the DIV*?

Comment: @justLearning: If you want to show the text in, say, `columnOne`, you would do that by retrieving the text from the object using the property names you've created. E.g.: `var question = columnOne['$100'];` gives you the string `"On the world political map, where were some of the major states and empires located about 1500 A.D. (C.E.)?"`

Comment: Could you show me an example of what that would look like - or how it looks different from what I already have written?

Comment: @justLearning have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rStuM/3/ and http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rStuM/4/

Comment: @Stano it started from somewhere and is going somewhere completely different

Comment: The Jsfiddle is very good; however, it returns randomly - not the specific order that I have written it. Therefore, in each column when I click the link I would like the corresponding question to appear.

Comment: I have updated the HTML code to my question. Do I need to make a table instead? The column should be: column 1 = $100, $200, $300, $400, $500

Comment: @justLearning If I click third `li` in `rowTwo` what should be displayed?

Comment: @justLearning is it `F` or `G`?

Comment: it is 'G' that will appear - sorry

Comment: Thank you so much! I have spent hours trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 2):

You first need to remove those commas in your `.text()` function then use the `JSON.stringify()` method to print those objects.

Your function should be like this:

```
$("#clueContainer").text(JSON.stringify(columnOne) +  
    JSON.stringify(columnTwo) +  
    JSON.stringify(columnThree) + 
    JSON.stringify(columnFour) + 
    columnFive[foo]);
```

You may also refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254227/how-to-fetch-array-keys-with-jquery) StackOverflow question.